# Question on Linear Transformation...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find a linear transformation $T$ that maps the unit square to a figure with an area of $14$ and a vertex at $(4,2)$.

I don't really know how to solve this type of problems? I just started studying Linear transformations.

Please give any hint.

Also suggest me some link to study linear transformations.

Comment: Let $f:\,x\to Ax$ be that transformation with $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. You're given $\det A=14$ and $A.(1,1)^T=(4,2)$ -- 3 equations on 4 variables. You'll have 1 free variable then. I did look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences) to reveal what's a linear transformation.

Comment: It will be even simpler to impose $A.(1,0)^T=(4.2)^T$.

Comment: @jean Sorry, I really didn't solve this problem completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the unit square be $(0,0), (1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}.$

1. Constraint on the image of vertex, say $(1,0)$, being send to $(4,2)$ can be written :

$$A\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

giving $$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

2. constraint on the area of the image ; it is known that the ratio of the area of the transformed figure to the area of the initial figure is equal to the determinant of the transformation, which means for example that

$$\det A = \begin{vmatrix}4&c\\2&d\end{vmatrix}=14$$

wich mean that any choice of $c$ and $d$ such that

$$4d-2c=14$$

provides an answer, for example with $d=4$ and $c=1$.

As a consequence, the image of the unit square is the parallelogram :

$$A'(0,0), B'(4,2), C'(5,6), D'(1,4).$$